Difference between 'elements related to an element' and 'elements to which an element is related' in a relation.
Suppose we define a non symmetric relation R:{1,2,3,4}--->{1,2,3,4}:R={(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,3),(3,4),(4,1)}
then is there a difference between 'elements related to an element (say 1) in R' and 'elements to which an element (say 1) is related in R' ?
from what I am able to understand the former can mathematically be written as {b:(b,1) belongs to R} while latter can mathematically be written as {b:(1,b) belongs to R} because when say (a,b) belongs to R then we say that a is related to b ie. aRb
therefore elements related to 1 here in R are {1,4,2} and elements to which 1 is related are {1,2,3}

Using "related" in natural language for non-symmetric relations is awkward, but as you demonstrated it can be done. Of course the underlying fact is true regardless of what words we use: ${b : (a, b) \in R}$ and ${b : (b, a) \in R}$ are different sets in general.

Yes there is. In the language of order theory, each of the two sets is the dual of the other.
Consider the is-descended-from relation $D$ defined on people at a birthday party for person $b$. As it happens for this party, the set of people $p$ such that $p \,D\, b$ includes only $b$’s children, and the set of people $p$ such that $b \,D\, p$ includes only Granny and Gramps.
The former set is $b$’s descendants (present at the party), and the latter is $b$’s ancestors.

Thankyou very much :)
